# How to get the value from a dictionary as an integer during dictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

So here's the rundown I am currently taking api information and feeding it into the requests module to make it readable in the console:

```
response = requests.get(STOCK_ENDPOINT, params=stock_params)
response.raise_for_status()
stock_info = response.json()
yesterday = stock_info["Time Series (Daily)"][f"{YESTERDAY}"]
```

When printed yesterday returns:

```
{'1. open': '671.64', '2. high': '694.6999', '3. low': '670.32', '4. close': '688.72', '5. adjusted close': '688.72', '6. volume': '21516348', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'}
```

From here I am now using dictionary comprehension to get yesterdays closing price:

```
y_close = {k:v for (k,v) in yesterday.items() if k == "4. close"}
print(y_close)
```

Which returns:

```
{'4. close': '688.72'}
```

From here I am a little stuck on how to get the number itself from the dictionary for use in math later. Can anyone help me?

Have tried using y_close.values() but that returns

```
dict_values(['688.72'])
```

And im honestly stumped on how to proceed. Have tried using stuff like for loops and functions but can't seem to get just the raw number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = {'4. close': '688.72'}

float(list(a.values())[0])

float(a['4. close'])

float([v for k,v in a.items()][0])

[float(v) if "close" in k else 0 for k,v in a.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't think to add float into the list comprehension i'd tried. Dunno how i'd missed that!